# How can we change RAPL power limits in Haswell CPU?

Tags: linux, x86, hardware, intel, power-management

I am trying to change the power limits defined in the RAPL registers of my system. It is a Haswell CPU.

I have tried two approaches:

1. Using the MSR regsiters:
   I try to use the rdmsr (as root) command to read the contents of the 0x610 regsiter in which the power limits are defined. Then I am using the wrmsr command to write to it. I try to change the first bit of this register from 1 to 0 to unlock the power limits.

rdmsr -p0 0x610 returns: 8042828a001a8208

wrmsr -p0 0x610 0x0042828a001a8208 executes without any error message

Then i read the register again using: rdmsr -p0 0x610
It prints: 8042828a001a8208

As you can see, i am trying to change the first hexabit from 8 to 0. The rest is same. but it won't change the bit.

2. The other approach I tried to change the power limits was to edit the system powercap files. I migrate to the directory /sys/class/powercap/intel-rapl/intel-rapl:0

Here we have these two files:

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Nov 21 15:45 constraint_0_power_limit_uw and

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Nov 21 15:42 constraint_1_power_limit_uw

As you can see I have changed the privileges of the first file. The first one has value 65000000 and the second one has value 81250000. i try to change the value of the first to (say) 62000000 but when I try to save it the file trows an FSync failed (E667)error. I unset Fsync using 'set nofsync' command but then it throw filesystem full error(E514) . I reduce my file consumption and even rebooted the system but then it throws E509.

What am I doing wrong? I need to manipulate the RAPL power limits to regulate my system's TDP. Is there any other way to change RAPL limits?
Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some [info here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/powercap/powercap.txt)

Comment: Bit 64 of MSR 0x610 is a `LOCK` bit (see Intel SDM, Volume 3, section 14.9.3, `MSR_PKG_POWER_LIMIT`). You can't unset the lock bit once it's set, that's its whole purpose. And you can't play with the rest of the register after it's set. If it's set by the BIOS, you're going to have to do a lot of work to allow yourself to fiddle with that register, requiring either fiddling with BIOS settings or altogether reflashing it.